# Replacing an object in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to know how to replace an object which is in a `ArrayList<Animal>`.

I have a array list called `ArrayList<Animal>`. This list only has 5 animals listed init.

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
animal.setName("Lion");
animal.setId(1);

ArrayList<Animal> a = new ArrayList<Animal>();

a.put(animal); // likewise i will be adding 5-6 animals here.
```

Later on, i will take an object from this array list and modify it.

```
Animal modifiedAnimal = new Animal();
 animal.setName("Brown Lion");
    animal.setId(1);
```

Now i need to add this Animal Object to the `ArrayList<Animal> a`   array list. I need it to replace the previous `Animal` object which we named it `Lion`. How can i do this ?

Note: I don't know the Index where this object is added.

Comment: Override equals then you can use `indexOf` to determine index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at bellum's post for how to do this with an `ArrayList`. However, you'd probably be better off with a `HashMap<String, Animal>`

```
HashMap<String, Animal> animals = new HashMap<String, Animal>();
// ...
Animal animal = new Animal();
animal.setName("Lion");
animal.setId(1);
animals.put(animal.getName(), animal);

// to modify...

Animal lion = animals.remove("Lion"); // no looping, it finds it in constant time
lion.setName("Brown Lion");
animals.put(animal.getName(), animal);
```

Comment: I didn't try your code yet. But i want to know how will it update the HashMap, by just modifying the name of the Lion ? Did you miss something ? like, do i have to say this `animals.put("Lion", lion);` ?

Comment: @user1315906: By the way, if you need to access the animals by ID as well, you could have two different `HashMap`s with both keys, just make sure to update correctly if you do that.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to **replace** the `Animal` in the list with a whole new `Animal`, use [`List#set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29). To use `List#set`, you'll need to know the index of the `Animal` you want to replace. You can find that with [`List#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

If you just want to *modify* an animal that is already in the set, you don't have to do anything with the list, since what's stored in the list is a reference to the object, not a copy of the object.

Answer (score 6):

You must first get its reference from list and simply modify it. Like this:

```
Integer yourId = 42;

for (Animal a : animalList){
     if (a.getId().equals(yourId)){
          a.setName("Brown Lion");
          //...
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: What hapence if i want to do the comparison using the ID of the animal, and not by using getName as shown in the example -->`if (a.getName().equals("Lion")){`

Answer (score 2):

```
for(Animal al: a){
    if(al.getName().equals("Lion")){
       al.setName("Brown Lion");
       al.setId(1);
       break;
    }
}
```

1. Loop thru your list untill you find the Animal
2. change its attributes
3. break outta loop

Answer (score 1):

You could use HashMap for this easily. Your key is id and value is animal object.

by using `get` method you can take the animal object you required and do the modification and again put new Animal against same key.